Get calendar event titles and locations through Microsoft Graph API with "Can view titles and locations" permission
Let's say a user shared their calendar with "Can view titles and locations" permission.

Is there a way to view the titles and locations of the events on this user's calendar using Graph API?
List events (/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events) and list calendarView (/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendarView) endpoints are both returning ErrorAccessDenied.
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}

I know I can use the getSchedule endpoint, but that doesn't return the titles and locations of the events.

You would need a minimum of Reviewer to calendar as a delegated right to be able to read the events endpoint. If you have the correct permissions eg titles and locations then getSchedule will return the Subject (Title) and Location properties in the scheduleItems array. The only case where then may not work is if you query Meeting Rooms as they can be set to remove the Title for privacy reasons.
